# PHP copy failing to copy file but not reporting any errors

Tags: php, copy, mkdir

I am attempting to copy 3 files from an existing folder to a new folder that has just been made with mkdir. So far no luck. The files do not copy into the folder and PHP is also reporting no errors. I checked the code online with the PHP syntax checker and it came back okay.

I think I have my formatting wrong in the copy command but I am not sure what the specific problem is. I have tried using no quote and single quote on the file to be copied and on the destination but neither worked. I double-checked the url for the file to be copied and it's correct.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = new \stdClass();
        $file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index, $content_range);
        $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow((int)$size);
        $file->type = $type;
        if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
            $this->handle_form_data($file, $index);
            $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
            if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
                mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
             //Attempting to add new code below
             //let's secure the new folders with 3 copied files
              $copy1 =copy(/files/.gitignore, '$upload_dir'.'/.gitignore');
              $copy2 =copy(/files/.htaccess, '$upload_dir'.'/.htaccess');
              $copy3 =copy(/files/index.html, '$upload_dir'.'/index.html');
            }
            $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
            $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
                $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
            if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
                // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
                if ($append_file) {
                    file_put_contents(
                        $file_path,
                        fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND
                    );
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
                }
            } else {
                // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                    $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                );
            }
            $file_size = $this->get_file_size($file_path, $append_file);
            if ($file_size === $file->size) {
                $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
                if ($this->is_valid_image_file($file_path)) {
                    $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
                }
            } else {
                $file->size = $file_size;
                if (!$content_range && $this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                    unlink($file_path);
                    $file->error = $this->get_error_message('abort');
                }
            }
            $this->set_additional_file_properties($file);
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

Comment: May be the problem is giving pagth at the time of copy. try to give full path of the folder where you want to save the files

Comment: Thank yo for the comment Anant. I used your suggestion and changed the code like this: ' $copy1 =copy('/files/.gitignore', '/files/'.'$upload_dir'.'/.gitignore');
              $copy2 =copy('/files/.htaccess', '/files/'.'$upload_dir'.'/.htaccess');
              $copy3 =copy('/files/index.html', '/files/'.'$upload_dir'.'/index.html');' Still the same issue the files are not copying when the new folders are created.

Comment: What i want to say just hardcode full path of your new created directory and then try to execute copy. IF HAPPEN THEN  the path you are giving is not correct or your code is not working perfectly from initial.

Comment: Thank you Anant for your help. It was a path issue and also a syntax issue. This is the format that actually worked: ' $copy1 =copy('files/.gitignore', 'files/'."$test".'/.gitignore');'

Comment: Good to here that your problem is solved.